# Hot reloading with state stops working when using a Higher Order Component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hot-loader, higher-order-components

Has anyone else ran into this issue? I'm working on a react native app and hot reloading with state works fine using react native debugger and redux devtools, but once I make a change within a higher order component or make a change to a component that uses a higher order component, my redux state disappears from the devtools and everything needs a hard refresh. When I make changes to files without higher order components everything works as expected.

Comment: yup, it won't work. I guess, maybe data is stored globally, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the root of the app is wrapped in the store / hot-module

Comment: I think the root of the app is Fela and we're using react native navigation doesn't react native hot loading work without that?